# The conversion of the varchar value '359342067417520' overflowed an int column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am creating a web app in mvc-5 angularjs using SQL Server as a database

At one place i am inserting the details of all the mobile I purchased, I created a user defined type in SQL Server which looks like this

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TyDetails] AS TABLE
(
    [transmid] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [modelNumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Color] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [productType] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [emeiNo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [emeiNo2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Uprice] [float] NULL,
    [brandid] [varchar](50) NULL
)
```

and a read only stored procedure which looks like this

```
create proc [dbo].[Ins_details]
    @tbl_data TyDetails readonly
as
begin
    insert into tblTransactionD (TransactionMId, modelnumber, color, producttype, brandid, emeino, emeino2, price)  
        select * 
        from @tbl_data
end
```

Now the main table here is named as `tblTransactionD` which looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblTransactionD]
(
    [TransactionDId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TransactionMId] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [ProductName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ModelNumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Color] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ProductType] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [BrandId] [int] NULL,
    [EmeiNo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EmeiNo2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Qty] [int] NULL,
    [Price] [float] NULL,
    [ProductTax] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_tblTransactionD] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TransactionDId] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I am passing the data through **Data table and TYPE** into my database

I am passing **359342067417520** in **dr["emeiNo"] = em1[id].ToString();** here

here is my code of mvc

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("transmid");//
    dt.Columns.Add("modelNumber");//
    dt.Columns.Add("color");//
    dt.Columns.Add("productType");//
    dt.Columns.Add("emeiNo");//
    dt.Columns.Add("emeiNo2");//
    dt.Columns.Add("Uprice");//
    dt.Columns.Add("brandid");
    for (int id = 0; id < ps.Modelnumber.Split(',').Length; id++)
    {
        string[] mod = ps.Modelnumber.Split(',');
        string[] col = ps.Color.Split(',');
        string[] typ = ps.phoneType.Split(',');
        string[] em1 = ps.emei.Split(',');
        string[] em2 = ps.emei2.Split(',');
        string[] pri = ps.Uprice.Split(',');
        string[] act = ps.onetwo.Split(',');
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["modelNumber"] = mod[id].ToString();
        dr["color"] = col[id].ToString();
        dr["productType"] = typ[id].ToString();
        dr["emeiNo"] = em1[id].ToString();
        dr["emeiNo2"] = em2[id].ToString();
        dr["Uprice"] = Convert.ToDouble(pri[id].ToString());
        dr["transmid"] = getgu.ToString();
        dr["brandid"] = ps.brandid.ToString();
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("Ins_details");
cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

but on my execution line I am getting the error

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The conversion of the varchar value '359342067417520' overflowed an int column.

Comment: The max value for int is `2,147,483,647`

Comment: Pro tip: if you have a "number" and it doesn't make sense to perform mathematical operations on it (e.g. one phone number times another phone number) then store them as strings, not numbers.

Comment: you can also use bigint in sql

Comment: In c# use long or Int64

Comment: Well, it's only ~10^5x bigger than int supports...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you are inserting `emeino` which is string into `brandid` column which is int. Check the order of your columns in INSERT command in stored procedure. Last four columns in table type are not the same order as you wrote in procedure.

You should change `SELECT * from @tbl_data` to actually write all columns in same order you made for INSERT

```
insert into tblTransactionD (TransactionMId, modelnumber, color, producttype, brandid, emeino, emeino2, price)  
select transmid,  modelnumber, color, producttype, brandid, emeino, emeino2, price    
from @tbl_data
```

Also, `brandid` column is `INT` in Database, but `VARCHAR(50)` in table type and `string` in C#. Fix it to be consistent through all layers.